# Navigation (right, left, up and down Arrows) in CSS

Tags: html, css

I currently have the navigation tools in a div as shown below:

**Update:** After some effort I now have controls like this;

[image]

What I need to achieve is as below (Please ignore the background color but need containing div as circle as shown in image):

[image]

My HTML code is as below:

```
<div class="mapPanTools">
        <div style="display: block" id="panUp"></div>
        <div style="display: block" id="panDown"></div>
        <div style="display: inline" id="panLeft"></div>
        <div style="display: inline" id="panRight"></div>
</div>
```

**Update:** My edited CSS code

```
.mapPanTools {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 10;
        margin-top: 22%;
        left: 14px;
        padding: 0px 0px !important;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
.blockDisplay {
display: block;
}
#panDown {
background-image: url(iconUrl);
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
}
#panUp {
background-image: url(iconUrl);
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
}
#panRight {
background-image: url(iconUrl);
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
}
#panLeft {
background-image: url(iconUrl);
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
}
```

Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: share your CSS .

Comment: I updated my question and added css code

Comment: and what did you try in order to obtain the layout you need? you simply created 4 divs with background

Comment: @TemaniAfif I have updated the css code. Please check and guide me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
.mapPanTools {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 10;
        margin-top: 22%;
        left: 14px;
        padding: 0px 0px !important;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 64px;
        height: 64px;
    }
.blockDisplay {
display: block;
}
#panUp, #panRight, #panDown, #panRight {
    display: block;
    position: absolute
}
#panDown {
background-image: url(iconUrl);
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
bottom: 0;
}
#panUp {
background-image: url(iconUrl);
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
top: 0;
}
#panRight {
background-image: url(iconUrl);
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
right: 0;
}
#panLeft {
    background-image: url(iconUrl);
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    left: 0;
}
```